# Plot multivariate data in Python

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I have a data of human activity performing various leg movements. The data consists of X, Y, Z gyro sensor orientation. Data looks like below:

Activity 1:

timestamp,              X rad/sec,      y rad/sec,   z rad/sec

1474242172.0203,      -0.440601,     -2.377124 ,  -0.379635

1474242172.09023,    -0.402881,      0.03603,    -0.436877

1474242172.11018,    -0.079664,      0.071131,     -0.969909

Activity 2:

1474242172.13019,   0.504345,  0.21577,        -1.171976

1474242172.15017,   1.485681,  0.95263,        -1.050102

1474242172.32995,  2.162143,   -2.888519,  -1.274397

1474242172.34995,  2.178419,   -2.332485,  -1.130116

Activity 3:

1474242172.27003,  2.71125,        -0.618401,  -0.394154

1474242172.29002,  2.421668,   -1.14887,   -0.846701

1474242172.30999,  2.212555,   -2.497823,  -1.096355

I have collected for 3 activities for a 7 days. Each data is in separate csv file. I would like to plot this data in Python/R. I want to take avg of X value, y value and Z value for each activity for one day and plot them using parallel coordinates. Activity(1,2,3) on one coordinate, Day 1 through Day 7 on different coordinates. X,Y,Z being different colors flowing. My classification of activity is not present in data set. I have to program the ticks for Activity.

Can any one suggest if parallel coordinates is the right way to show consistency of each activity over 7days? Or is their any appealing way to plot them in either surface plot or a 3D plot.

Can anyone provide inputs? I greatly appreciate for any advice or example of similar situation.

Comment: I tried ploting a 2D sub plots for each activity for each day. I am still figuring out the way to plot parallel coordinates graph to show all the information in a single plot.

Answer (score 1):

in python, you could use [pylab](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) to plot in 3d using something like: `plt.plot(x_vals_list,y_vals_list,z_vals_list)` . If you have more than 3 dimensions you can use [Principal Component Analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) to break down those dimensions into 3 major components.